# Problem with running batch files from within my application

Tags: c#, windows, shell, command

I've been trying to create a simple application to backup my Windows Server databases aswell as a whole server backup.
For this I want to use batch files which are being executed by my application.
I tried several approaches but for some reason it always fails so I'd be happy if you could help me out.

Batch file BACKUPSERVER:

```
wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:D: -include:C: -allCritical -quiet
```

I have to run the bat as administrator or it fails due to missing permissions.

C# code:

```
        static Task<int> RunProcessAsync(string fileName)
        {
        ............
        Process p = new Process();

        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C \"D:\\SQLBACKUP\\BACKUPSERVER.bat\"";
        p.Start();

        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();

        }
```

Debugging says 'wbadmin wasnt found'. 'runas' activated or not doesn't make any difference.

```
                 ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = fileName;

        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
       // startInfo.Verb = "runas";

        var process = new Process

        {

            StartInfo = { FileName = fileName },
            EnableRaisingEvents = true

        };
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;

        process.Exited += (sender, args) =>
        {
            tcs.SetResult(process.ExitCode);
            process.Dispose();
        };

        process.Start();
```

Also doesn't work.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I'm able to run commands like shutdown but wbadmin doesn't work whatsoever...

Comment: At first glance, this appears to be a working directory problem. Your .NET exe is going to try to execute the batch file from whatever its current working directory is. As such, unless wbadmin is in that working directory, or on the global PATH, it won't be found.

Comment: I tried putting the .exe into System32 folder but no success aswell

Comment: The default working directory is rarely the System32 folder. There is a property on ProcessStartInfo called WorkingDirectory. Set that to the absolute path for the wbadmin tool.

Comment: The command "C:\Windows\System32\wbadmin.exe" wasnt found

C:\Windows\System32>C:\Windows\System32\wbadmin.exe start backup -backupTarget:D: -include:C: -allCritical -quiet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem:

1. Make sure ure compiling for 64bit if u intend to use your application on 64bit system, otherwise it will redirect to different subfolders and wont find 'wbadmin.exe'.
2. Run wbadmin with ProcessStart or run a batch but without direct cmd input, so use this with filename = batch file or wbadmin with startInfo.Arguments:

   ```
       ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
   startInfo.FileName = fileName;

   startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
   startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
   startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
   ```

   // startInfo.Verb = "runas";

   ```
   var process = new Process

   {

       StartInfo = { FileName = fileName },
       EnableRaisingEvents = true

   };
   process.StartInfo = startInfo;

   process.Exited += (sender, args) =>
   {
       tcs.SetResult(process.ExitCode);
       process.Dispose();
   };

   process.Start();
   ```
3. Make sure u request administrator rights